# org.jboss.logging.Logger + Quarkus Framework + Log File Configuration Issue

Tags: quarkus, logfile, jboss-logging

I have been traying to generate a Log file with the fallowing configuration,
(suggested by Quarkus https://quarkus.io/guides/logging):

## application.properties LOGS

```
quarkus.log.level=ALL

quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus".level=ALL
quarkus.log.category."org.hibernate".level=ALL

quarkus.log.console.level=ALL
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %h %N[%i] %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) %s%e%n
quarkus.log.console.color=true

quarkus.log.file.enable=true
quarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/quarkus-test.log
quarkus.log.file.level=ALL
quarkus.log.file.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %h %N[%i] %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) %s%e%n
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-file-size=1M
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index=100
```

#POM FILE

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager> 
                        
                          <org.jboss.logging.Logger>org.jboss.logging.Logger</org.jboss.logging.Logger>
                        <quarkus.log.level>ALL</quarkus.log.level>
                        <quarkus.log.file.level>ALL</quarkus.log.file.level>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                    
                                         <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager> 
                                        
                                         <org.jboss.logging.Logger>org.jboss.logging.Logger</org.jboss.logging.Logger> 
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
```

but the Log File that has been created is empty, I would like to know how to solve this.

Thank in advance.

J2RE